# Why does this Closure require a return at the outer function also?

Tags: javascript, closures

For Closures in Javascript, I have the code below, pretty simple but I am trying to understand the intricacy of Closures and this code below does not work the way I think it should. I am using Node.js terminal window (not browser for console.log).

```js
function init() {
  let name = 'rumbo'; // i created a simple variable inside the parent function (i get this)

  function displayname() {
    return (name); //inner function with a **return** of the variable above (i get this also)
  }
  displayname(); //* see note below
}

console.log(init()); //as per my thought, this should console log 'rumbo' but it does not.
```

*This spits out 'undefined'. (I get that; when you do not state specifically or use a return/or console.log at the outer function, you will get undefined. However, in this case the displayname() function is **called** at the end of outer function and should return 'name' from the inner function **return** value. But it doesn't.

So that is my question, why does this outer function call, **not** return the result (in this case 'rumbo') when it is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`init` does not return anything, so `console.log(init())` will only log `undefined`.

`return` will *only* return the value from the currently executing function - it won't `return` all currently executing functions all the way up the call stack. (That'd be quite messy and near impossible to use, after all.) So, you have to `return name` inside `displayname`, so that `displayname` returns something. But then you want the caller of `init` to receive the value, so `init` has to `return` as well, with `return displayname()`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So it will not return the inner function's return values.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly, because you're not telling it to return the value. A function will return `undefined` unless you tell it to return something else.

If you did this instead...

```
function init() {
    let name = 'rumbo';  // i created a simple variable inside the parent function (i get this)

    function displayname() {
        return (name);    //inner function with a **return** of the variable above (i get this also)
    }
    return displayname(); //* see note below
}

console.log(init());  //as per my thought, this should console log 'rumbo' but it does not.
```

you would get what your where expecting.

You could also think of it like this...

```
function init() {
    let name = 'rumbo';  // i created a simple variable inside the parent function (i get this)

    function displayname() {
        return (name);    //inner function with a **return** of the variable above (i get this also)
    }
    const x = displayname(); 

    return x;
}

console.log(init());  //as per my thought, this should console log 'rumbo' but it does not.
```